# Wronskian second solution of $2(1-x)y''-3y'+\frac{y}{x}=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question had asked to use Wronskian method to show a second solution to the DE

$$2(1-x)y''-3y'+\frac{y}{x}=0$$

is $$y_2(x)=1 + y_1(x)\operatorname{atanh}[\sqrt{1-x}]$$

where $y_1(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$

using the formula needed:

$$y_2(z)=y_1(z)\int^z\frac{1}{y_1^2(u)}\exp(-\int^up(v) dv)du$$

where $p(z)=\frac{-3}{2(1-z)}$

I get to this point:

$$y_2(z)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z}}\int^z\frac{1-u}{u^2}\exp(-\frac{3}{2}\log(1-u))du$$

the $\exp$ and $\ln$ cancel so:

$$y_2(z)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z}}\int^z\frac{1-u}{u^2}(1-u)^{-\frac{3}{2}}du$$

now I'm thinking to cancel one of the $(1-u)$ terms but I tried that and it didn't work out so I don't know how best to continue and where to get the arctan...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If you simplify the integral in the last expression, you have $$\int_ 0^z\frac{du}{u^2\sqrt{1-u} }$$ This looks to be a good candidate for a substitution using $\sqrt{1-u}=v$ that is to say $u=1-v^2$.

Now think about partial fraction decomposition.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: umm sorry...how did the integral simplify to that?

Comment: $(1-u)\times (1-u)^{-3/2}=\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-u}}$ if I am not wrong